# How to verify if an url ends with mp4?

Tags: android, url, mp4

Can anyone help me to verify if a certain url ends with mp4 on android?

Comment: You need to more information on the context. Where exactly do you need to check this? What's your input? Is it actually an `URL` object or merely a `String`?

Comment: I have this array : String[] target that contains url-uri

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just take your URL as String and use the function of String as follows:

```
String str=new String(URL);
if(str.endsWith(".mp4")){
//your stuffs
}
```

Here is [link](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-videoview-example) for VideoView example.

Comment: Corrected. Its `With` not `Width`. Edited it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you know how to play a mp4 on android?

Comment: There is VideoView widget through which you can play it.Just search and i have given the link above.Thr is one example.But keep in mind you have to test it using real phone only.It will not work with emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is what you are looking for:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)

Simply compare the `String` with the `endswith` method to see if it ends in .mp4.

Assuming the URL is a `String` ofcourse, but you haven't said otherwise.

Comment: Thanks.This is the solution. Do you know how to play a mp4 on android?

Comment: Sorry, I do not. But I'm sure you will be able to find something with a bit of Googling.